# LinkedList (custom) add() return NullPointerException

Tags: java, data-structures

I am trying to implement data structure Linked List (Singly) however by adding elements returns NULLPOINTEREXCEPTION.

```
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;

public class Linkedlist<ANYTYPE>{

private Node head;

Linkedlist(){
    head = null;
}

public void add(ANYTYPE data){
    head.next = new Node<>(data, head);
}

public void traverse(){
    if(head == null) throw new NoSuchElementException("List may be empty");

    Node temp = head;

    while(temp != null){
        System.out.println(temp.data+" ");
        temp = temp.next;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Linkedlist<String> l=new Linkedlist<String>();
    l.add("one");
    l.add("two");
    l.traverse();
}


private class Node<ANYTYPE>{

    private ANYTYPE data;
    private Node next;

    Node(ANYTYPE data, Node next){
        this.data = data;
        this.next = next;
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Add proper tag to get right answer and try formatting your code before posting.

Comment: Ask yourself what is the value of `head` when the list is empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the add() method, you'll have to check if there is any node yet (as you correctly do in the traverse() method).
if (head == null), you cannot access the .next member. Instead, your first element to add should be assigned to head itself.

Comment: Thanks Rahul, Florian I added null check if head is empty in each method.   public void add(ANYTYPE data) {
  if (head == null)
  head = new Node<ANYTYPE>(data, null);
  head = new Node<>(data, head);
 }

Answer (score 0):

Yeah cause in your constructor you are setting `head` to `null` as seen below

```
Linkedlist(){
    head = null;
}
```

Then in `Add()` trying to do `head.next` and so the exception

```
public void add(ANYTYPE data){
    head.next = new Node<>(data, head);
}
```